# How to spawnProcess with multiple arguments in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to start a process via twisted. I am parsing a JSON file the following structure with multiple commands in it:

```
{
"key"     : "test",
"cmd"     : "cat",
"args"    : "/opt/vinci/rxDaemons.json | grep cmd",
"restart" : 5,
"auto"    : 0
}
```

the command I am attempting is very simple; I am searching the file for the term "cmd" (as I am sure you could pick out)

the code I am using to spawn the process is as follows:

```
cmd, args, uid, gid, env = self.processes[name]

proto = LoggingProtocol()
proto.service = self
proto.name = name
self.protocols[name] = proto
self.timeStarted[name] = self._reactor.seconds()
newArgs = str(cmd).split() + args.split()
self._reactor.spawnProcess(proto, str(cmd), args=newArgs, env=env, uid=uid, gid=gid )
```

The response is:

```
cat: |: No such file or directory
cat: grep: No such file or directory
cat: cmd: No such file or directory
```

It then cats the entire file

I am assuming it us running cat on each of the args but I have no idea why

How do I properly use more than one arg with spawnProcess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `|` isn't an argument to `cat`, it's [part of `bash`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html). In `POpen` you can add `shell=True` to the command, but that doesn't seem to be available in Twisted. The "correct" solution is probably to implement the piping in Twisted, not in bash.

EDIT: Actually in your case, this is a ["useless use of `cat`"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat), just run this command instead:

```
grep cmd /opt/vinci/rxDaemons
```

Comment: It is useless when it comes to creating that specific output, however, it is useful in that is has multiple arguments. I suppose the that the command you suggested is multiple arguments as well...